# Pyspark not displaying anything when calculating skewness on one column

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am not able to see results of an aggregate function in pyspark dataframe with display function. I am calculating skewness on one column only at a time

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

val1 = [(20,100),(100,100),(50,100),(0,100),(0,100),(0,0),(0,50),(0,100),(0,20)]
cols = ['val1','val2']
tf = spark.createDataFrame(val1, cols)
display(tf.select(f.skewness(tf['val1']),f.skewness(tf['val2'])))
```

It gives me the following output

```
DataFrame[skewness(val1): double, skewness(val2): double]
```

I know since its an aggregate function I can use

```
tf.agg(f.skewness('val1')).show()
```

but I want to use display function, but it's coming empty. Any clues?

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: Jupyter Notebook

Comment: I am able to see the output even with your code, with the display function itself. I am running on same Jupyter notebook in databricks cloud.